# How to define function name using variable?

Tags: php, function, variables

how to define function name (in PHP) using variable, like this?

```
$a='myFuncion';
function $a() {.......}
```

or like that?

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: you should use the tags to define the language, that is what draws the experts into your question

Comment: 11k rep. This must be a test?!

Comment: how i've forgot that... that's PHP. 
sorry guys.

Comment: What's the point of this question? You've provided two options.. which works?

Comment: Possibly explain a little more

Answer (score 2):

The only way I know to give a fixed name to a function is to use eval, which I would *not* suggest.

More likely, what you want is to stuff a function IN a variable, and then just call that.

Try this:

```
$a = function() {
   echo 'This is called an anonymous function.'; 
}
$a();
```

**EDIT**:
If you want to be accessible from other files, then use GLOBAL variable:

```
$GLOBALS['variable_name'] = 'my_func_123';
${$GLOBALS['variable_name']} = function() {
   echo 'This is called an anonymous function.'; 
};

// Executing my_func_123()
${$GLOBALS['variable_name']}();
```

See also: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php

Comment: You can if you make sure the variable is available there.

Comment: That's... one way to do it, although not one I would recommend either.

Comment: yes, now it's done. thanks... p.s. why not recommend? if so, how you could have

Comment: Read up on scopes to see where variables are available: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php